# Hex manipulations

Tags: c++, mfc

There are very nice `Hex.Decode(string hexString)` and `Hex.ToHexString(byte[] hexArray)` methods in BouncyCastle crypto library (C#, Java).

How to make the same conversions with `CString` variable, that stores hex-string for example `"af010cdb"` to `unsigned char*` and vice-versa in C++?

Answer (score 2):

These are real easy to implement:

```
CString ToHexString(const CByteArray& Array)
{
    CString sHexString;
    for (int i=0; i<Array.GetSize(); i++)
        sHexString.AppendFormat(_T("%02X"), Array[i]);

    return sHexString;
}

void DecodeHexString(const CString& sHexString, CByteArray &Array)
{
    if (sHexString.IsEmpty())
        return;

    int nLen = sHexString.GetLength();

    if ((nLen % 2) != 0)
    {
        ASSERT(FALSE);
        return;
    }

    Array.SetSize(nLen/2);

    int nByte = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<nLen; i += 2)
    {
        CString sByte = sHexString.Mid(i, 2);
        BYTE byte = (BYTE)_tcstol(sByte, NULL, 16);
        Array[nByte] = byte;
        nByte++;
    }
}
```

Comment: @storojs72 If you've found the answer to your question, you can Accept it make it the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `std::string` and `std::vector<unsigned char>`

Edit: removed `sscanf` and `sprintf`

```
std::vector<unsigned char> str_to_byte(std::string str)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> bytes;
    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::string part;
    while (ss >> std::setw(2) >> part)
    {
        try {
            int i = std::stoi(part, 0, 16);
            bytes.push_back(static_cast<unsigned char>(i));
        }
        catch (...) {//error msg
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}

std::string byte_to_str(std::vector<unsigned char> bytes)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::uppercase;
    for (auto c:bytes) 
        ss << std::setw(2) << static_cast<unsigned int>(c);
    return ss.str(); 
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> bytes = str_to_byte("EF010203A0A1FFz");
    std::string str = byte_to_str(bytes);
    cout << str << endl; //should print "EF010203A0A1FF"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sscanf` and `sprintf` feel a bit out of place. Using [stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)s is more in line with the surrounding C++ code.

Comment: update: removed `sscanf` and `sprintf` as suggested by IInspectable